# Creating INSERT INTO sql statement to append records to a table using a form's combo-boxes

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-insert

I have just begun building a new database to store medical records. I'm trying to set up a form that will handle all the end user functions, which for now is simply to assign treatments to a patient from a list. I have three combo-boxes on the main form: Category, Treatment, and Patient. The Category combo-box pulls from the table tblCategories, and the Patient combo-box pulls from the table tblPatients. When a Category is selected, it updates the Query qryTreatmentsByCategory, which has criteria to limit the treatment records shown to those in the selected category. This Query is the source of the Treatment combo-box on the main form.

The goal is for the data in each combo-box to be appended to the table tblPatientReport, which has an autonumber primary key field and then a field for each of these three values. The PatientID field and the CategoryID field both append without issue; however, the TreatmentID field does not. Rather than append the Treatment's ID (the primary key of the table tblTreatments), it instead appends the selected treatment's position in the query.

For example, when choosing "Bladder Scan,' the Treatment ID should be 106. However, it is the 15th record in its' category when sorted alphabetically. Because the source data for the Treatment combo-box is the query qryTreatmentByCategory, the Treatment ID is instead listed as 15. However, the query's first field is the TreatmentID from tblTreatments, so I'm not sure why it instead chooses the record's position on the query.

The code for the INSERT INTO statement is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnAddTreatment_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblPatientReport (ptrPatientID, ptrTreatmentID, ptrCategoryID) values (cmbPatientName.Value, cmbTreatment.Value, cmbCategory.Value)"
End Sub
```

The code for the query qryTreatmentsByCategory, the source for the Treatment combo-box, is as follows:

```
SELECT tblTreatment.TreatmentID, tblTreatment.trItem, tblCategory.CategoryID
FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblTreatment ON tblCategory.CategoryID = tblTreatment.trCategory
WHERE (((tblCategory.CategoryID)=[Forms]![frmMain]![cmbCategory]));
```

How do I get the INSERT INTO statement to use the TreatmentID field that serves as the primary key for the tblTreatments, while still using qryTreatmentsByCategory as the source for the Treatment Combo-box. Again, the first column in qryTreatmentsByCategory is the TreatmentID field from tblTreatments, so I'm not sure why that data is not being pulled.

This is my first time submitting a question, so if I have bee unclear on anything just let me know and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: Make sure the the combobox's bound column is 1. Otherwise the value of the combobox will the taken from another column of the query. E.g. if it is = 3, then the CategoryID will be returned as value.

Comment: I have the bound column set to zero; when it's set to 1, it returns a Type conversion failure when the INSERT INTO function is executed.

Comment: Is there a type mismatch between `tblTreatment.TreatmentID` and `tblPatientReport.ptrTreatmentID`? The bound column should be 1. If it is 0 the list index is used instead. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.boundcolumn

Comment: `tblTreatment.TreatmentID` and `tblPatientReport.ptrTreatmentID` are both Number format so I'm not sure why that type conversion failure occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bound column of the treatment combo box must be 1.

The SQL string must be constructed with the combo box values.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblPatientReport (ptrPatientID, ptrTreatmentID, ptrCategoryID) values (" _
  & cmbPatientName.Value & ", " & cmbTreatment.Value & ", " & cmbCategory.Value & ")"
```

RunSQL will not automatically replace the combo box references inside the string by their values.

Comment: I entered that code, and it now gives the following error message: "Run-time error '3075': Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'Bladder Scan.'" It looks like the code is pulling up the Treatment Name rather than the Treatment ID. The combo-box is set to choose from and display the Treatment Names `qryTreatmentByCategory.trItem` rather than the Treatment ID `qryTreatmentByCategory.TreatmentID`. But the bound column is set to one, and `TreatmentID` is the first column in `qryTreatmentByCategory` so I'm not sure why it's pulling `trItem` instead.

Comment: What you see in the combo box depends on the settings in Column Width. If the width of the first column is 0 then you will see trItem in the display. This is different from the bound value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved! I had coded the row source for the Treatment combo-box as

```
SELECT [qryTreatmentByCategory].[trItem]
FROM qryTreatmentByCategory
ORDER BY [trItem];
```

I changed this to just read `qryTreatmentByCategory` and just hid the first column with the `TreatmentID`.

Thank you so much for the help, I've replaced the old SQL `INSERT INTO` statement with the one you've provided and it works great.